# Angular [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: angular, promise

My angular project has been working perfectly fine but suddenly hot reload has stopped working and anytime I try to refresh the page I get this error. I followed the path of the error where the "file does not exist" but I have no idea what this file is meant to do so I can't replace it. Not sure how to fix this error or if theres something that I did wrong to cause it but if you have experienced this or have an idea of the fix I would appreciate it. Thanks. Error below:

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/kevinbacon/Desktop/dev/kbcoding/frontend/kbcoding/.angular/cache/16.2.8/angular-webpack/f1ebbe6c6eeda44ad327399b3c7637f8751878c4/4.pack'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/kevinbacon/Desktop/dev/kbcoding/frontend/kbcoding/.angular/cache/16.2.8/angular-webpack/f1ebbe6c6eeda44ad327399b3c7637f8751878c4/4.pack'
}
```

Note: When I follow the path there is a '4 2.pack' file. I tried to make a new file called '4.pack' but it was automatically renamed to '4 3.pack'... not sure if that helps.

Comment: can you try a `ng cache clean` and restart ?

Comment: Super Helpful Thank you! If you post this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your angular got corrupted for whatever reason.

try a `ng cache clean` !

Comment: It worked! Thank you!